# Setting up Electron with React Typescript CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, electron

**_____ Project description _____**

I started my Typescript & React project as a web app and I am currently in the process of converting that fully to an Electron app. I am having some trouble with this though.

**_____ Where I am currently at _____**

I followed [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@kitze/%EF%B8%8F-from-react-to-an-electron-app-ready-for-production-a0468ecb1da3) to get Electron to work. It works fine, other than that the `electron.js` file (in the tutorial called `main.js`, I placed it in my `src` folder, not the `public` folder) is a javascript file. This does not hinder my application from running, but I'd prefer having it in Typescript format. That is what I am stuck on. I converted it to a Typescript file, but I can't point to that from my `package.json` config.

**_____ Problem Description _____**

From my understanding, the `main` property in `package.json` needs to point to this `electron.ts` file. But of course, the file does not get processed correctly because it is not a javascript file.

**_____ Question _____**

How can I somehow point to the `electron.ts` file? Where does the transpiled code, generated on runtime, reside? Perhaps I could point the `main` property to there?

**_____ package.json _____**

```
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node scripts/start.js",
    "build": "node scripts/build.js",
    "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
    "electron-dev": "concurrently \"BROWSER=none npm run start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
    "electron-pack": "build -- em.main=build/electron.js",
    "preelectron-pack": "npm run build"
  },
  "main": "src/electron.ts",
  "homepage": "./",
  "build": {
    "appId": "com.example.electron-cra",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "assets"
    }
  },
  ...
```

Comment: [Clone to try a simple Electron app (in TypeScript)](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start-typescript) may be a good starting point.

Comment: @Mikaeru I looked at that. It uses `tsc`, which is not what the React CRA seems to be using.

Comment: Sorry, I must confess I have no clue... 

Comment: I have tried that approach (from the same tutorial) too, and I am stuck at the same point. I think the problem is, that once you put the main.ts into your src folder, it gets compiled into the bundle.js. So we either need a way to call electron with the bundle.js, but not the same entry point which the CRA app uses, OR we need a way to create a second bundle (lets call it electron.js) for electron from main.ts. However, I fear that creating  a second bundle means ejecting from CRA - which I prefer not to.

Answer (score 0):

I made a boiler plate starter pack which contains many applied bug fixes that I had to face when using react with electron and typescript and has auto monitoring of typescript changes to reload the electron app for faster development.

https://github.com/nateshmbhat/electron-react-ts-starter/

It works fine with Create react app and no need of ejecting it .

Answer (score 0):

The fastest route that I found to getting typescript up and running was with [`electron-webpack`](https://webpack.electron.build/).

With the [add-ons](https://webpack.electron.build/add-ons), it's got your requirements covered. I've used this to [great success](https://github.com/duality-solutions/pShare) for an electron-react-redux application.